# Floating wrapfigure and page break

Tags: wrapfigure

I use the [`wrapfig`](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf) package to have some text wrapping around a figure. I want the wrapfigure to float so I use the capital letter L to set the placement of the figure. When the figure is at the bottom of a page and that there is not enough space left, wrapfig decides to put the figure on the next page. But it puts it where the next paragraph starts. Is it possible to make wrapfig place the figure at the top of the next page?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{10cm}
\rule{10cm}{5cm}
\end{wrapfigure}
WRAP PAR BEGIN test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test SHOULD BE HERE test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test WRAP
PAR END

EFFECTIVE WRAP PAR test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a documented limitation. The documentation also suggests that you ignore it until the final version, then manually place the figure where you want it. I assume manual placement means you observe where the page and line break takes place, then simply end the paragraph there with `{\parskip=0pt\par}` and start your figure after that with the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: @Dan Ok. But I'd like to know if there is a way to change this behaviour. I don't like the idea of manually placing floats in a document with several hundreds of pages.

Comment: Despite the so-called floaing options, `wrapfigure`s are not really floats. It would be very difficult, perhaps even impossible, to make one automatically float to the position of a page break, but it might be theoretically possible to convert it to a normal float. The number of pages in your file seems irrelevant; what counts is the number of figures that require intervention. If you have too many to make the effort worth your while, you might consider avoiding `wrapfigure`s.